# Why Gtmetrix loads unknown html asset?

Tags: html, assets, gtmetrix

I am developing and testing a website's ([pablitogreco.com](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/www.pablitogreco.com/3fVA7oLQ)) performance through Gtmetrix. In the waterfall chart the service finds and loads an html I do not recognize.

Why Gtmetrix loads an unknown html asset?

[image: html assets]
[image: first html]
[image: second html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason a little after I posted the above question. The server was trying to load an **empty variable** from the html code that was missed. That tiny issue caused so much trouble.